# How change the icon on the game?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I need help with adding an icon to my application using the "Haxe" engine. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this using XML or code? Also, I am attaching an image of my VSC code and folder for reference:

[VSC Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NXOo.jpg) (**Visual Studio Code**)

> [Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZG0c.jpg) (**Appliaction**)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use HaxeFlixel which is based on OpenFl/Lime engine. Haxe is only the language.

According to the [Lime documentation of the icon settings](https://lime.openfl.org/docs/project-files/xml-format/#icon), your xml looks correct.

Then you need to have a folder named **icons** in the same level that your project.xml. In that folder, you should place all your icons. You could use only one, especially if it's in svg.